# Chef DK instead of Chef Client

Tags: security, chef-infra

Is installing Chef DK instead of Chef Client in an enterprise scale a good idea? Mostly from the security perspective? Doesn't it add many unnecessary tools in the client that increase the attack vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually unnecessary to replace Chef Client with ChefDK on nodes that are managed by Chef. Its versioning is different so that you're tied to the included version of Chef Client and don't have the full choice.
And yes, if you want the argument of attack vectors, there are additional tools installed.

But probably it is easier to rant against this when understanding the thinking of the person suggesting this.

Comment: To be clearer, Chef-client installers are for servers, ChefDK is for workstations.